# Closing flutter web app (flutter PWA) by clicking on a button

Tags: flutter

I create a flutter web app and use it as a PWA in my java-script website I opened it using iframe.

I want to close my PWA by tapping on a button by `SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop')`.

I tried this code but not working:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
  },
  child: Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4), child: Icon(Icons.close, color: BpColors.white, size: 20)),
);
```

I also tried using exit(0) but it makes the website to go to previous page not just closing the PWA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

close_clicked is the event name that my javascript is listening to.

```
import 'dart:html' as html;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class GlobalCloseButton extends NoControllerWidget {
  const GlobalCloseButton({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        html.window.parent?.postMessage("close_clicked", "*");
      },
      child: Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4), child: Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.red, size: 20)),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to close web app by `SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop')` because this only works for mobile applications. anyway, instead of it you can use `window.close()` to close web app window. but unfortunately it may not working in some browsers because they do not allow to close window from JS for security reasons.

```
import 'dart:html';

/// your another codess

GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    window.close();
  },
  child: Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4), child: Icon(Icons.close, color: BpColors.white, size: 20)),
);
```

By the way, there is a package named [flutter_window_close](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_window_close) you can try it.

happy coding...